# Customised Android Home Screen with default Widget

Tags: android, android-launcher

I have customised the home screen sample application which was there in Android SDK samples, and now trying to add a clock widget there.This home screen sample doesn't have any option in the menus to add widgets.
And my objective is to just a Digital Clock and Whether in the Home screen.
So can you pls suggest me about how to proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a different home screen as the basis for your research. The [Launcher2](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git;a=tree) home screen is in the Android open source project, and there may be third-party home screen implementations that are open source as well. You will be looking for classes like `AppWidgetHost` and `AppWidgetHostView`.

Comment: Hi,This Launcher2 is giving lot of errors while importing it into eclipse.That's why I have started with HOME Launcher.

Comment: @user825042: Launcher2 is part of the firmware. You cannot load it as an SDK application. You have to build it as part of the overall firmware. http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html